# Bootsrap Modal on hide method does not trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Modal:

```
<div id="modalRelease" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Revision Release</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div style="text-align:center; color:red;"><p>You are about to release to the next Revision level.</p></div>
                <div style="text-align:center;"><p>Description Required:</p></div>
                <div>
                    <textarea name="RevisionDescription" id="RevisionDescription" class="form-control" placeholer="Description..." data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Please enter a description."></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <div class="alert alert-danger" id="RevisionSubmitError">A description is required.</div>
                <div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="ReleaseSubmit">
                        <i class="fa fa-save"></i> Submit
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">
                        <i class="fa fa-remove"></i> Cancel
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Button Click Capture Event:

```
   $(document).on("click", "#ReleaseSubmit", function (event) {
        if ($.trim($('#RevisionDescription').val()) == "") {
            $("#RevisionSubmitError").fadeIn("slow", function () { });
        }
        else {
            submitForm('release')
        }
    });
```

Then, trying to capture the Hide event so that the error message is not still visible should the user close and then re-open the modal, but this isn't ever triggering:

```
$('#modalRelease').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#RevisionSubmitError').hide()
})
```

Where 'RevisionSubmitError' is a div inside the modal-body.  The div is never hidden.  I have also tried hidden.bs.modal.

Using Bootstrap v3.3.6

Comment: You are trying to hide a div inside a modal when the modal is hidden ?

Comment: Correct.  It's a div that contains any errors in a form in the modal.  So, let's say the user opens the modal, submits the form with errors.  The div RevisionSubmitError is displayed.  Then the user closes the modal.  The next time the user opens the modal, I want RevisionSubmitError to not still be visible.

Comment: Why do you need inline `onclick` handler? Just add `data-dismiss="modal"` attribute to your button which does close the modal too.

Comment: That's how I had it at first, but when the hide.bs.modal method didn't work, I tried this.

Comment: since you are hiding the modal not removing it normally  the  #RevisionSubmitError will be hidden event if you call it after the modal is not shown, could you please post your html

Comment: I posted all of the modal html

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling `.modal('hide')` on the modal after the form submit? That is the call which needs to be made for 'hide.bs.modal' to fire

Comment: How / where would I call .modal('hide') if the form is never submitted? The issue is that if the text box is empty, we show the div RevisionSubmitError.  Then if the user closes the modal w/o submitting the form, I want RevisionSubmitError to be hidden when the modal re-opens.